# Upgrate from 5.0 to 5.1 - Now mocked tests won't pass

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-5.1, mockery

I wonder if anyone can help me figure this one out. Under Laravel 5.0, all my tests ran fine, but since updating to 5.1(.17) this morning, any test which is using `Mockery` now fails with something similar to:

```
vagrant@homestead:~/Code/nps$ php phpunit.phar tests/Workers/AutomatedEmailerWorkerTest.php
PHPUnit 4.6.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Configuration read from /home/vagrant/Code/nps/phpunit.xml.dist

E

Time: 16.27 seconds, Memory: 56.50Mb

There was 1 error:

1) TRP\Nps\Tests\Workers\AutomatedEmailerWorkerTest::testEmail
Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method connected() from Mockery_0_Illuminate_Queue_QueueManager should be called
 exactly 1 times but called 4 times.
```

And the test in question:

```
class AutomatedEmailerWorkerTest extends TestCase
{
    private $autoWorker;
    private $returned;
    private $payload = [
        'content' => 'PHPUnit Test Email Content',
        'subject' => 'PHPUnit Test Email Subject',
        'blade_template' => 'emails.interaction',
        'closed_loop_step_id' => '1',
    ];


    public function testEmail()
    {
        Mail::pretend(false);
        self::pretendQueue();

        $mock = Mockery::mock(
            'Swift_Mailer[send]',
            [
                Mockery::mock('Swift_Transport')->shouldIgnoreMissing()
            ]
        );

        Mail::setSwiftMailer($mock);
        $globalMessage = null;

        $mock->shouldReceive('send')->atLeast()->times(1)
            ->andReturnUsing(function ($msg) use (&$globalMessage) {
                $globalMessage = $msg;
            });

        $response = $this->call(
            'POST',
            '/api/v1/automatedemail',
            $this->payload,
            [],
            [],
            ['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' => 'Bearer '.$this->getAuthToken()],
            []
        );

        $this->assertEquals($this->payload['subject'], $globalMessage->getSubject());
        $this->assertContains($this->payload['content'], $globalMessage->getBody());
        $this->assertNotEmpty($globalMessage->getTo());
        $this->assertNotEmpty($globalMessage->getFrom());
    }
}
```

I've been banging my head against the screen for the past hour and I can't figure it out, it's bound to be something stupid...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get around this by Mocking the `Queue::push` and `Queue::connected` methods in each test case that require it, due to some tests not caring about queues. Like so:

```
\Queue::shouldReceive('push')->atLeast();
\Queue::shouldReceive('connected')->atLeast();
```

Just in case it helps people out, as that was a head scratcher!